# Approaching from the right or from the left?

Tags: calculus, limits

Simple question:

If I have $\lim_{x \to -3^-}f{(x)}$ and I'm looking at a graph, am I approching -3 from the direction of +$\infty$ to -3 (as in going in the negative direction)? Or am I approaching -3 from the direction of -$\infty$ (as in the positive direction)?

edit: sorry corrected my mistake in the question.

Comment: $f{(x)} = \lim{x \to -3^-}$ doesn't make sense to me. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: I assume the OP meant to write something like $\lim_{x\rightarrow -3^{-}}f(x)$, but I agree it's not clear what exactly.

Comment: I think he means $\lim_{x \to -3^{-}} f(x)$

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39826/meaning-of-lim-p-to-0/39838#39838

Comment: oops. Thanks i typed up this question in a hurry.

Comment: @Chandru: Yes, it looks like that question came first, but this one is really the more general one. There might be an argument for keeping them both open, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Zev: Me too! That's why I put related and not duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"$\displaystyle\lim_{x\rightarrow-3^{-}}$" denotes approaching $-3$ from the left (i.e. from $-\infty$), to the right (i.e. in the positive direction). The Wikipedia page on [one-sided limits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-sided_limit) helps clear things up a bit.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that helped a lot :).

Answer (score 2):

If you find the $\lim_{x\to -3-} f(x)$ notation confusing, you can also write
$$\lim_{x\uparrow -3} f(x)$$
and think, "this is the limit of $f(x)$ as $x$ increases toward $-3$."  Likewise, you can use 
$$\lim_{x\downarrow-3} f(x)$$ 
to denote the right-hand limit.

I readily concede that  is a matter of taste, but matters of taste such as this one affect readability, and that's important.